# No view found for id, while calling child fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

So i have on `MAIN ACTIVITY(M)`, two `FRAGMENTS(F1, F2)` and a `BUTTON(B)` on `F1`.

Now when the main activity is started `F1` is automatically loaded which is fine, what I want to do is start `F2` when I click on `B` which is on `F1`.

Following is my code for Fragment1 that is HomeFragment:

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

 public static HomeFragment newInstance() 
 {
        return new HomeFragment();
    }

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState){


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEnq);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InfoFragment infoFragment = new InfoFragment();
            /*FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, infoFragment).commit();
            */

            FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom, 0);
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_container,infoFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    ImageAdapter adapter1 = new ImageAdapter(this.getActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter1);

    return rootView;

    }

@Override
public void onDetach(){
    super.onDetach();

    try{

        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this,null);

    }catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  } 
}
```

`frame_container` is the name of the container in the `main_activity.xml`. I have tried the following posts:

- [Android Fragment no view found for ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508044/android-fragment-no-view-found-for-id)
- [No view found for id 0x7f090005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940192/no-view-found-for-id-0x7f090005)
- [No view found for id for fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819187/no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment)

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Post your fragment_home layout and Main Activity code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is your trying to add the `Fragment B` as a Child Fragment of `Fragment A` in `R.id.frame_container`, and I suspect the `frame_container` is not a view in Fragment A layout(R.layout.fragment_home).

You can always add a child fragment using getChildFragmentManager(), but it needs a container to hold the fragment.

In your case , I don't see any need of adding the Fragment B as a child for Fragment A.

You need to replace the Fragment A attached in Activity with Fragment B using the the Activity Fragment Manager

Change the line in `Button` onClick()

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

as

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: thank you... i will give it a try.... but it would have been great if i could call a child fragment.. can u give me an example or a tutorial link for that....